# Kendo Grid Template: Inline Condition (?:) where if true I display a value in a link. If false I display an error text msg in the column instead

Tags: templates, kendo-ui, grid

Please excuse any syntax errors as it is not my question.
I noticed some escape characters are not displaying in my href, so just know they are there in the code.

This would display the value in a link in a column
template: '<a class"whatever" href="#"> #=value#',

This accounts for null values and doesn't display a link.

template: '<a class"whatever" href="#"> #=value !=null ? value: ""#',

What I am trying to achieve is to be able to use similar syntax to display a link and when the value is null it would display an error message that isn't a link.

Similar to this where it would display the value or the error.

template: ' #=value !=null ? **value** : "Invalid Entry"#',

This is where the problem comes in.

I cannot seem to get the syntax right to make that value a link again.

template: ' #=value !=null ? **<a class"whatever" href="#"> #=value#** : "Invalid Entry"#',

I've tried various combinations of wrapping it with ', ", # and nothing seems to work.

I'm trying to avoid building a separate function and calling it to determine the output, so I'm trying my best to keep this inline if I can.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. I've done it here over several lines so that it is easier to read and understand but you can put it as a single line into your code (I forget if you need to escape the # in the href once or twice):

```
# if (value) {#
    <a class"whatever" href="\\#"> #=value# </a>
#} else {#
    <span>Invalid Entry</span>
#}#
```

The # marker is used to switch between javascript and outputting html (any # within html needs to be escaped). It is also used to mark data values to be output. Those can be rendered either as html, for example:

```
#:value#
```

or with html encoding:

```
#=value#
```

You can't put javascript code in those which is why you are struggling with your template.

Comment: I created the if-else solution originally, but I was trying to keep as an ternary conditional 
 result to keep it uniform with the others.  
But in the end, I stayed with the solution I had which was similar to what you provided.